# Can svc.predict return the result along with probabilities for the other classes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am using SVM classifier for multi class classification.

I want svc.predict to return the result along with probabilities for the other classes also.

The result i got is like this:

print(svclassifier.predict([[79,93,60,50,50,80,81,88,87,100,100,71,100,83,100,100,75,70,100,60]]))

Expected OutPut is the category number= 27

Output Obtained is: 27

But I want the output in the form of probabilities....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `predict_proba` method (see [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba)).

Please also consider the note seen in documentation:

> The probability model is created using cross validation, so the
>   results can be slightly different than those obtained by predict.
>   Also, it will produce meaningless results on very small datasets